# IF statement for multiple date ranges

Tags: excel, if-statement

I built a tracker for my platoon to manage numerous training dates based on completion.  Each sheet tracks different things and I'm trying to make a coversheet that pulls data from each sheet to give an overall snap shot.  I'm trying to create and IF formula for if any of the dates in a certain row are over due, it reports as over do.  I can do it with 1 or 2 but not with 14 different dates.  Is this possible?

Comment: You question is not clear. Please edit your question and include some sample data then explain logic to gain your desired output.

Comment: There are probably simpler ways to do what you want, but you need to  add considerable detail to what you have posted.

Comment: Ok so I have a spread sheet with a column of all of my soldiers. Each subsequent column has numerous training events with the date they completed them. I have rules set for them to change colors when they get within a date range of one year from their completion (305 days, 335 days, 365 days) so I can track when they will be coming due. I created a column right next to their name and I basically want it to read if any of the dates within a specific soldiers row are overdue to report over due. My idea was an IF statement but I can’t figure it out. Does all of that make better sense?

Comment: The rules I’m currently using are cells that “contain cell value between” =TODAY()-335 and =TODAY()-365. I want a column to read if any of those dates inputted are over 365 to report over due. The purpose is so my front cover sheet pulls the data from that column (which I’ve figured out) to give my commander an over view of the platoons statuses concerning multiple sheets of data like the training sheet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Column A is personnel names, column B is overall status, columns C-Q are trainings they’re required to complete annually. Each meeting point of a column and row has the date they completed their training. I have rules that make that date turn yellow when it is within 60 days, red in 30, black when over due, and green if they are current. I want column B to show somehow if any of those dates within a persons row are yellow and be overridden if any are red or black.  Otherwise I want it to be green. I want it to give an overall status to show they have something coming due or over due.